# Im trying to create an array of user Objects in local Storage using vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple quiz app and i would like to store an object of each user and their score in an array stored in local Storage. The problem is every time I initiate the function instead of adding a new object to the array the existing object values are changed instead

```
//JS code

function storeUsers(userObject) {
    if (localStorage.getItem(users) === null) {
        users = []
    } else {
        users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(users))
    }

     const userScoreTemplate = function (usersName, usersScore) {
            this.user = usersName;
            this.score = usersScore;
        }

        newUser = new userScoreTemplate(userName, score);
        


    users.push(userObject);
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users))


}

storeUsers(newUser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss quotes in `localStorage.getItem`.

I also recommend you separate the functionality of your function like below:

```php
class UserScoreTemplate {
    constructor(userName, userScore) {
        this.user = userName;
        this.score = userScore;
    }
}

function storeUsers(userObject) {
    let users = [];

    if (localStorage.getItem("users")) {
        users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    }

    users.push(userObject);
    localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(users));
}

const newUser = new UserScoreTemplate("John", "Doe");

storeUsers(newUser);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing quotes around `users` :

```
if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct reference should solve it, the arguments passed to `function(usersName, usersScore)` will not be accessible outside the function, thats why your code doesn't work. You're passing parameter to the `storeUsers` function so that should be used whereever needed.

```
newUser = new userScoreTemplate(userObject.userName, userObject.score);
```